# Use codec error handler for print() in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding

It is well known that the `encode()` has a `error` param for codec error handling, for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# "发" and "财" are not available in 'big5' encoding
text = "发财了".encode('big5', errors='replace')
```

However, there is not an `errors` param for `print()`, and if we simply write:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print("发财了")
```

A `UnicodeEncodeError` exception is raised if it's run in a command prompt with big5 encoding (for example, in a Traditional Chinese version Windows).

Is there a way to make `print()` act like `encode()`, which accepts more handlers such as `replace`, `backslashreplace`, or `xmlcharrefreplace`, so that the string can be printed safely without raising an exception?

Comment: What? Why don't you do `print("发财了".encode('big5', errors='replace'))`?

Comment: Because we are not sure if the user is always running the script under a system with 'big5' encoding. And we want python to print most printable chars on any system. Also it is possible that the subject to be printed is not a `str`, and therefore the `encode()` cannot be used.

Comment: Additionally `print("发财了".encode('big5', errors='replace'))` will print bytes `b'??\xa4F'` instead of str. If you mean `print("发财了".encode('big5', errors='replace').decode('big5'))`, my response is as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my current solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys

def safeprint(*args, errors='backslashreplace', **kargs):
    """
    Print safely and skips error decode.

    Acts like print() with an additional "errors" argument to determine the
    error handler for codec errors and accepts non-str-or-None types for the
    "sep" and "end" arguments.
    """
    e = (kargs['file'] if 'file' in kargs else sys.stdout).encoding
    args = [str(x) for x in args]
    sep = str(kargs['sep']) if 'sep' in kargs and kargs['sep'] is not None else " "
    end = str(kargs['end']) if 'end' in kargs and kargs['end'] is not None else "\n"
    text = sep.join(args) + end
    kargs['sep'] = ""
    kargs['end'] = ""
    print(text.encode(e, errors).decode(e, errors), **kargs)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    safeprint("Hello World!", "你好世界！", "ハローワールド", "हैलो वर्ल्ड")
    safeprint("Hello World!", "你好世界！", "ハローワールド", "हैलो वर्ल्ड", errors="ignore")
    safeprint("Hello World!", "你好世界！", "ハローワールド", "हैलो वर्ल्ड", errors="replace")
    safeprint("Hello World!", "你好世界！", "ハローワールド", "हैलो वर्ल्ड", errors="backslashreplace")
    safeprint("Hello World!", "你好世界！", "ハローワールド", "हैलो वर्ल्ड", errors="xmlcharrefreplace")
    safeprint("Hello World!", "你好世界！", "ハローワールド", "हैलो वर्ल्ड", sep=None, end=str)
    safeprint("Hello World!", "你好世界！", "ハローワールド", "हैलो वर्ल्ड", sep=" -发- ", end=" -财- \n")
    with open("safeprint_big5.log", "w", encoding="big5") as f:
        safeprint("Hello World!", "你好世界！", "ハローワールド", "हैलो वर्ल्ड", file=f)
    with open("safeprint_gbk.log", "w", encoding="gbk") as f:
        safeprint("Hello World!", "你好世界！", "ハローワールド", "हैलो वर्ल्ड", file=f)
    with open("safeprint_utf8.log", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        safeprint("Hello World!", "你好世界！", "ハローワールド", "हैलो वर्ल्ड", file=f)
```

This approach makes a custom function `safeprint()` that acts like native `print()` with these differences:

1. Has an additional `errors` argument to determine how to handle codec errors (`backslashreplace` as default).
2. The `sep` and `end` arguments accept types other than str or None.

`safeprint()` checks the encoding of the ouput file that native `print()` are supposed to write into and encodes all text arguments beforewards, and therefore all printable chars are printed as-is and all unprintable chars are printed as transformed.

Although encoding and decoding beforewards for all texts being printed seems inefficient, native `encode()` and `decode()` are C based and are running very fast. In a test I print some articles with a utf8-compatible plain text for 5000 times in a utf8 console, the native `print()` takes `0:00:02.366799` and `safeprint()` takes `0:00:02.915871`. It proves that the performance drop is almost negligible.

The above script can be saved as a module script, say `safeprint.py`. Other scripts can use `from safeprint import safeprint` and use `safeprint()`, or can even use `from safeprint import safeprint as print` to overwrite the native `print()` so that `print()` will work just like `safeprint()` does.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the your print function with try .. except block, and catch the UnicodeEncodeError exception:

```
try:
   print("发财了")
except UnicodeEncodeError:
   handle_encode_error()
```

You can decide how to convert the string in the exception block.